# how to get a popover frame of specified width and height in ipad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i am using an popover view in my application,when i went through the samples i found how to create a popover view but in the sample code the popover view is getting displayed to whole page. i want the popover frame of specified width and height when i click the button.

```
-(IBAction) settingsGo:(id) sender{

NSLog(@"Go");
```

if (self.popoverController == nil)

```
{
    PopOver *lang = [[PopOver alloc]
                   initWithNibName:@"PopOver" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    UIPopoverController *popOver = 
    [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:lang];

    popOver.delegate = self;
    [lang release];

    self.popoverController = popOver;
    [popOver release];
}



CGRect popoverRect = [self.view convertRect:[button frame]fromView:[button superview]];
popoverRect.size.width = MIN(popoverRect.size.width, 50);

[self. popoverController 
 presentPopoverFromRect:popoverRect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
```

so what changes i should make in the above code to get a frame of specified size of width and height.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Account is the class to be displayed.  popAccount is its instance. buttonA is the button on which after click the popOver will be displayed.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad

{
    popAccount = [[Account alloc] init];

        //[popAccount setDelegate:self];

        popOverControllerA = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popAccount];

        popOverControllerA.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(200, 200);   

 }   
    -(IBAction)togglePopOverControllerA {

        if ([popOverControllerA isPopoverVisible]) {

            [popOverControllerA dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

        } else {

            [popOverControllerA presentPopoverFromRect:buttonA.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
        }

    }
```

Further ask for any query..

Comment: CGRect popoverRect = [self.view convertRect:[button frame]fromView:[button superview]];
popoverRect.size.width = MIN(popoverRect.size.width, 50);
This two lines of code making me not to set the frame postion.wheni use this code popOverControllerA.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(200, 200); still its making the frame to place at the left corner

Comment: [popOverControllerA presentPopoverFromRect:buttonA.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES]; will make this the popover to come out from the buttonA frame

Comment: ya i added its working fine,but my button is right top corner when i click on button the frame is displaying in left top corner.i want it to display below the button

Comment: may be the delegates causing the problem so now i have edited code and removed the line         [popAccount setDelegate:self];
 and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Set `popoverController.popoverContentSize` to whatever size you want.

Comment: Thank u if i want the frame at particular postion what code i should add in the above code?

Comment: popOverControllerA.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(200, 200);

Answer (score 1):

In the root view to position

```
CGRect frame= CGRectMake(0,0, 0, 0);

[self.myPickerPopover presentPopoverFromRect:frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:0 animated:NO];
```

To size in the view controller contents being displayed in the popover

```
-(void)viewDidLoad

{


  self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(750,880);


 }
```